# Given two string S and T. Determine a substring of S that has minimum difference with T?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I have two string `S` and `T` where length of `S` >= length of `T`. I have to determine a substring of `S` which has same length as `T` and has minimum difference with `T`. Here difference between two strings of same length means, the number of indexes where they differ. For example: `"ABCD"` and `"ABCE"` differ at 3rd index, so their difference is 1.

I know I can use KMP(Knuth Morris Pratt) Pattern Searching algorithm to search T within S. But, what if S doesn't contain T as a substring? So, I have coded a brute force approach to solve this:

```
int main() {
    string S, T;
    cin >> S >> T;

    int SZ_S = S.size(), SZ_T = T.size(), MinDifference = INT_MAX;
    string ans;

    for (int i = 0; i + SZ_T <= SZ_S; i++) {    // I generate all the substring of S
        int CurrentDifference = 0;              // and check their difference with T
        for (int j = 0; j < SZ_T; j++) {        // and store the substring with minimum difference
            if (S[i + j] != T[j])
                CurrentDifference++;
        }
        if (CurrentDifference < MinDifference) {
            ans = S.substr (i, SZ_T);
            MinDifference = CurrentDifference;
        }
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

But, my approach only works when `S` and `T` has shorter length. But, the problem is `S` and `T` can have length as large as `2 * 10^5`. How can I approach this?

Comment: What do you mean with it _"only works when S and T has shorter length"_? What happens when you input a large string? Does it just take forever to complete or do you encounter any errors?

Comment: @churill It just takes forever.

Comment: If this is from an online judge, can you please share the link to the problem?

Comment: @MarcoZamboni No, it's not form an online judge.

Comment: in the strings can there be any characters or only few different ones?

Comment: @MarcoZamboni Though I have seen problem like this but never attempted to solve these problem. I was just wondering how to solve this kind of problem without brute force approach.

Comment: this reminds me of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352523/how-to-find-the-shift-that-minimizes-the-difference-between-two-vectors). The answer explains how to do it in NlogN instead of N^2 by using a FFT

Comment: @MarcoZamboni I have a kind of similar problem from an online judge. Link: https://codeforces.com/contest/1196/problem/D2

Comment: This is related to Sliding window I feel.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 there can be any characters.

Comment: You could optimize away the `ans = S.substr (i, SZ_T);` and just save the index where the currently best result starts.

Comment: @churill I did. But It didn't help either :/

Comment: @YaseenMollik still FFT would be applicable.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thanks. I will try solving this using FFT

Comment: @YaseenMollik I don't feel a site like Codeforces would expect a programmer to solve this using FFT.

Comment: @vivek_23 I wasn't solving this problem for Codeforces or any other online judge.

Comment: fwiw I dont really understand the given answer, I would rather use the characters ascii code, interpret them as time series, pad `T` with zeros to make it same size as `S` then FFT and convultion to find the minimum (basically as described in the link i posted), I think it is interesting, maybe ill take some time to write an answer later

Comment: @YaseenMollik Ohh, I got confused since you shared a similar problem link of codeforces. But I think it's doable using sliding window. I will let you know soon.

Comment: @YaseenMollik I just realized that SW doesn't apply here since each character shifts for each window, which would the same as brute force.

Comment: @vivek_23 I have just solved [this](https://codeforces.com/contest/1196/problem/D2) problem using Sliding Window. .Its kind of similar problem but here T consists only of 'R', 'G' and 'B'.

Comment: @YaseenMollik Not sure if it's doable by SW. How did you apply the window here? Or did you just represent R,G,B by some integer values for the window calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Let's maximize the number of characters that match. We can solve the problem for each character of the alphabet separately, and then sum up the results for 
 substrings. To solve the problem for a particular character, give string `S` and `T` as sequences 0 and 1 and multiply them using the FFT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform.

Complexity `O(|A| * N log N)` where `|A|` size of the alphabet (for an uppercase letter is 26).